# Linq: An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

How can i use GroupBy in linq expression using the same name?, I have the following code to get data from multiple entities. I have RP and SubParty tables both have a Name field and I want to display both but linq giving me the following error

> An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name

```
var rp = await context.RP.AsNoTracking()
        .Include(rp => rp.SubPartyNav)
        .Include(rp => rp.partyNav)
        .Where(rp => rp.ProductID == request.ID)
        .GroupBy(rpSp => new
        {
                rpSp.partyNav.PartyName,
                rpSp.SubPartyNav.PartyNav.PartyName })
        .Select(r => new RspDTO
        {
                PartyName = r.Key.PartyName,
                SubPartyName = r.Key.PartyName, })
        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Indeed you can't have two properties with the same name... Can you please clarify what you expect to happen when you do so? (Normally one would simply have different property names like `{a=pr.Name, b=rp.SomeOther.Name}` but it does not look like you are interested in it)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think it's more likely that OP didn't know that was possible with anonymous types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just explicitly give the properties names:

```
        .GroupBy(rpSp => new
        {
                PartyName = rpSp.partyNav.PartyName,
                SubPartyName = rpSp.SubPartyNav.PartyNav.PartyName })
        .Select(r => new RspDTO
        {
                PartyName = r.Key.PartyName,
                SubPartyName = r.Key.SubPartyName, })
```

Also, it looks more like you want `.Distinct()` instead of `.GroupBy()`, since you're only using the group key:

```
        .Select(rpSp => new
        {
                PartyName = rpSp.partyNav.PartyName,
                SubPartyName = rpSp.SubPartyNav.PartyNav.PartyName })
        .Distinct()
        .Select(r => new RspDTO
        {
                PartyName = r.PartyName,
                SubPartyName = r.SubPartyName, })
```

Comment: Here is my problem cdhowie,  SubParty also link back to rp as `rpSp.SubpartyNav.RPNav.PartyNav.PartyName` right now PartyName is duplicating i need PartyName to be rp PartyName or SubParty RP :) how can i do that?

Comment: @Babish I don't understand the question.